# MiniCssExtractPlugin fail to load css file inside node modules

Tags: vue.js, css-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I use MiniCssExtractPlugin in a project which has some problem when I import css file inside node modules in a vue file. Import statement:

```
import '../../../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css
```

Webpack config:

```
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { url: false }
      }
    ]
 }
```

No style has been applied using the above setting. I tried to create a test.css file and put around in different folder. All directory will work except inside node_modules folder. Please help.

Extra info:
If I replace MiniCssExtractPlugin with style-loader, everything will be ok.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'style-loader' },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { url: false }
      }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Did you specify the plugin properly in the plugins option with new MiniCssExtractPlugin()?